# Eclipse Markers View ID

Tags: eclipse, view, rcp, markers

Does anyone know the ID of Eclipse's Markers view? I'm trying to bind an activity to it to hide from my RCP application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the "Problem view" by "Markers view"?
If so the corresponding ID should be: menu:org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView

Moreover there is a cool feature on the Eclipse SDK called "Plugin Spy" that displays informations on the UI you just clicked on (so you can retrieve the corresponding ID). Just hit "Alt+F1" then click on a view. To have same kind of information for the contextual menu actions, hit "Alt+F2" then click on the action you want to spy.

Comment: No, I meant 'Markers View'. But thanks for the plug-in spy tip, the ID  is actually org.eclipse.ui.views.AllMarkersView

Answer (score 1):

The problem view is different from the markers view.
The marker view id is:

```
org.eclipse.ui.views.AllMarkersView
```